# PHP: iCal creations, how to make a new line in a description

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar

I'm using the following to create a calendar invite for outlook for a php script. However the \n doesn't give me a new line in outlook. Is there a way to do this? Seems silly if you can't!

```
  function addToCalendar($calEmail, $calSubject, $calDesc) 
  {

$calEmail = 'freelance@skinzy.org';
$description = $calDesc;
$message="BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20110718T121000Z
DTEND:20110718T131000Z
DTSTAMP:20110525T075116Z
ORGANIZER;CN=TOMS TEST:mailto:system@skinzy.org
UID:12345678
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP= TRUE;CN=Yup:mailto:sample@test.com
DESCRIPTION New \n Line
LOCATION: I AM THE LOCATION
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY: TEST SUMMARY
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

$headers = "From: From Name <From Mail>\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST;\n";
$headers .= '        charset="UTF-8"';
$headers .= "\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";


$subject = "Meeting Subject";
$subject = html_entity_decode($calSubject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');


if(mail($calEmail, $calSubject, $message, $headers)) {

    echo "sent";
}else {
    echo "error";
}


  }
```

It's the `DESCRIPTION New \n Line` part i'm having issues with.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Tom

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should replace \r\n with \n:

```
$description = str_replace("\r\n", "\\n", $description);
```

See also [Encoding newlines in iCal files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666929/encoding-newlines-in-ical-files/12249023#12249023)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `=0D=0A` for new line with the appropriate encoding:

```
DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:This is the first line.=0D=0AThe Second line.=0D=0AThe third line.
```

or an alternative approach (using base64):

```
DESCRIPTION;FMTTYPE=text/html;ENCODING=BASE64:PHA+Tm9ybWFsIDAgZmFsc2UgZmFsc2UgZmFsc2UgTWljcm9zb2Z0SW50ZXJuZXRFeHBsb3JlcjQ8L3A+DQo8YnIgY2xhc3M9ImNsZWFyIiAvPg==
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you create a new line using `\r\n`.

To go into further detail:

`\r` in ASCII is `CR` standing for "Carriage Return"
`\n` in ASCII is `LF` standing for "Line Feed"

Windows requires the combination of both while Linux systems simply use `\n`.

There is tons of information (probably more then you'd ever be interested to know) on [Wikipedia's Newline page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for that. I didn't know that. Outlook still doesn't see it as a new line though :(