# Google calendar ignores multiline text for ical description

Tags: php, calendar, icalendar

I am creating a ical feed with PHP, I am using following package: https://github.com/markuspoerschke/iCal

My feed contains following data:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID: http://example.com/calendar/feed.ics
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:P1W
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:568e935b7ff7
DTSTART;TZID=Germany/Berlin:20160130T080000
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTEND;TZID=Germany/Berlin:20160130T113000
SUMMARY:CLASS #23 (JS Fundamentals)
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:RAVISH TIWARI 8:40AM\nJavaScript Fundamentals:  \nDOM\n
Forms\nValidations\n\nQA session
DTSTAMP:20160106T093331Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

AS per RFC, you can have multi line description:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.5

Any line with more than 75 chars, should be folded:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1

Now, when I download the ICS file generated, and import it with Thunderbird, it is imported and all content of description field is displayed, but, Google Calendar only reads the description till first new line character is encountered.

Earlier, newline was not escaped properly, nothing was imported by Thunderbird as well, however, I made changes to new line escape as per suggestions from this thread:
[PHP: iCal creations, how to make a new line in a description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855606/php-ical-creations-how-to-make-a-new-line-in-a-description)

Google and Mac iCal sync other details alright, it's just the DESCRIPTION they got problem with.
While digging forums, I found this on google product forum:
[Multiline desc issue Google Cal](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/VPb5CLjZgZg)
This thread is quite old, I am not sure if issue in this thread is still valid.

Can someone suggest some workaround here, or point something that might be wrong with my feed data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DESCRIPTION property is not folded correctly.  All folded lines must begin with a whitespace character (a space or a tab).

It should look like this.  Notice the space at the beginning of the second line:

```
DESCRIPTION:RAVISH TIWARI 8:40AM\nJavaScript Fundamentals:  \nDOM\n
 Forms\nValidations\n\nQA session
```

Comment: There was issue with the iCS plugin, I fixed the problem in the plugin as well so that nobody struggles in the future https://github.com/markuspoerschke/iCal/pull/60